# Is there a way to change the zone of the LogOn and NotFound view

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have created a custom version of the LogOn and NotFound views for a custom theme, is it possible to change the zone they render in?

I've tried putting `<Place LogOn="MobileContent:1"/>` into the `placement.info` file to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

LogOn renders into Content, I don't think you can change this via placement. Why do want this to render somewhere else?

Are you looking to have other content displayed with the logon form alongside it? You will need to create a widget for that. I made a little module, although if I'm honest I didn't really test it much and I'm not sure I would trust it that much ^_^ However, the code is available and should point you in the right direction.

https://modaccountwidgets.codeplex.com/

Or, if you are feeling brave, it is on the gallery, ready to be installed ;)

https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.Mod.AccountWidgets

**EDIT**

Logon is just a shape so you could in theory just overwrite the logon url

```
yield return new RouteDescriptor
            {
                Priority = 1000,
                Route = new Route("Users/Account/LogOn",
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                                            {"area", Area},
                                            {"controller", "MyController"},
                                            {"action", "LogOn"},
                    },
                    new RouteValueDictionary(),
                    new RouteValueDictionary { { "area", Area } },
                    new MvcRouteHandler())
            };
```

And then in here create your logon shape and send it to the zone you want to using IWorkContextAccessor (inject this into your new controller), eg.

```
var logon = _orchardServices.New.LogOn().Title(T("Log On").Text);
contextAccessor.GetContext().Layout.Zones["MobileContent"].Add(logon, 1);
```

However, I can imagine this getting fairly messy. You may want to rethink how you are doing this. Although someone may have a better solution for you :)

Comment: We have 2 custom themes, one for the desktop version of the site and the other for mobile. The desktop theme contains the Content zone but we purposely left this out of the mobile theme so it doesn't output any widgets intended for the desktop site. So the MobileContent zone is the main content area for the mobile theme.

Comment: Edited, although I would recommend keeping Content zone ;)

Comment: But if I kept the Content zone I'd have the issue in my previous comment. Do you know of a way to avoid it? We could do a work around by hiding the widgets with CSS for example but we want to avoid the widgets being sent to the browser entirely for bandwidth reasons